# Tower property implication

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

I have been looking at the version of the tower property in this image.[image]

I'm struggling to derive the version of the tower property that I'm more familiar with from this version.

How does the above version imply that $E[E[X|F]]=E[X]$? What is the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $G$ in this case?

Comment: Take the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $E[X]$, all you know of the event $X$ is that it could be any event, so it means $X$ is given only under the knowledge that the entire space $\Omega$ has probability $1$ and nothing else. Hence the $\mathcal{G}$ in your example is given by $\{ \emptyset, \Omega\}$.